# xslt splitting string based on special character

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

My xml is as below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<DATA>
  <MR>
    <RECORD type="tb1">
      <heading>tblheading</heading>
      <ROWS>
        <ROW> dt1;dt2 </ROW>
        <ROW> dt3;dt4 </ROW>
        <ROW> dt5;dt5 </ROW>
      </ROWS>
    </RECORD>
   </MISMATCHRECORDS>
</DATA>
```

and i want to transform it to below html using xslt 2.0.  how will my xslt look like?

```
<table>
<tr colspan="2"><th>tblHeading</th></tr>
<tr><td>dt1</td><td>dt2</tr>
<tr><td>dt3</td><td>dt4</tr>
<tr><td>dt5</td><td>dt6</tr>
</table>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is always a single separator, you can use simply `substring-before()` anfd `substring-after()`. Otherwise use the `tokenize()` function.

Comment: there will always be only one ";".  which one will be more efficient?  can you give me sample code? thanks.

Comment: I don't know. Efficiency depends on the processor you use. And, no, I will not write your code for you. If you run into a **specific** problem, ask about it.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is probably

```
<xsl:template match="ROW">
  <tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(normalize-space(.), ';')">
       <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```